# Angular and NodeJS module 'foo' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I feel like I'm losing my mind because the answer should be so simple, I'm new to angular and nodejs and I'm trying to make an application that combines them both.

> "Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

public/controllers/Homecontroller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp').controller('homeController', homeController);

    function homeController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.fillerData = "FillerData"
    }
}) ();
```

public/Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dit is de index</title>
    <script src="res/js/angular.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
    <script src="controllers/homeController.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<h1>What</h1>
<body ng-controller="homeController as homeCtrl">
    {{ homeCtrl.fillerData }}
</body>
</html>
```

router/index.js:

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/index', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});
router.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/home.html');
});
module.exports = router;
```

and /server.js:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var routes = require('./router');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/', routes);
require('router/index.js')(app);

app.listen(3000);
console.log("App listening on port 3000");
```

All the necessary packages have been installed as well, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a new `module`, you need to pass an empty `array` as the second parameter (if you have dependencies to other modules, than tell the modules in the array), which will tell angular that you are creating a new module.

From the [**Documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('homeController', homeController);
```

If you want to get already created module, than you need to call like

```
angular.module('myApp',[])....
```

Comment: I can only say "wow...". This solved it all, thanks man I appreciate it.

Comment: @woodsprite hope you saw my answer :P

Comment: Yep but Suren was a minute earlier, I voted you up though!

Answer (score 3):

Your module should have empty dependencies injected, change as

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('homeController', homeController);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('homeController', homeController);
```

To:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('homeController', homeController);
```

It will **create** the [module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).